# how can I print the exit status inside of the code?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system-calls

how can I print the exit status of the child program within the father process? ( after wait() )

the code to get the exit status of the child process works, but I don't know how to print it after

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include <unistd.h>  // getpid
#include <stdlib.h>

void childProcess(void);
void fatherProcess(int childpid);

int num1, num2, oper_inizializzata;

int main() {

  int pid=fork();
  if (pid==0) {
    childProcess();
  } else if (pid>0) {
    fatherProcess(pid);
  } else { // pid<0
    printf("Creazione del processo figlio fallita!\n");
  }
}

void childProcess(void)
{
  printf("Inserisci il valore del primo numero\n");
  scanf("%d",&num1);
  printf("Inserisci il valore del secondo numero\n");
  scanf("%d",&num2);
  printf("Scegli tra 1 o 2 per il valore della variabile\n");
  scanf("%d",&oper_inizializzata);
  
  if(oper_inizializzata==1){
    int num1piu2=num1+num2;
    printf("num1 + num2 e' %d\n", num1piu2);
    exit(num1piu2);
  }
  else if(oper_inizializzata==2){
    int num1per2=num1*num2;
    exit(num1per2);}
}

void fatherProcess(int childpid)
{
  wait();
  //print exit status here
}
```

Comment: *the code to get the exit status of the child process works*. I don't see any code to get the exit status of the child process. Can you please point that out?

Comment: @kaylum That's the problem; it isn't there yet. OP wants to know what to do in `fatherProcess` to reap the exit state of the waited-on child.

Comment: Please read the [wait manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html). It even has an example there that does exactly what is being asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The question states “the code to get the exit status of the child process works,” implying OP does have code to get the exit status but, since it does not appear in the question, that they have not shown it to us.

Comment: See `man 2 wait`. You can do: `void fatherProcess(pid_t childpid) { int status;  wait(&status);  do { if (WIFEXITED(status)) { printf("exited with code %d\n",WEXITCODE(status)); break; }  if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) { printf("exited with signal %d\n",WTERMSIG(status)); break; } ... } while (0); }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing exit status code of child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306764/capturing-exit-status-code-of-child-process)

Comment: @kaylum thanks, even if being a beginner I wouldn't know how to apply that example to my code ;(

Answer (score 2):

From the `man` page of `wait`

> pid_t wait(int *wstatus);

> If  wstatus  is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information
> in the int to which it points.  This integer can be inspected with  the
> following  macros  (which take the integer itself as an argument, not a
> pointer to it, as is done in wait() and waitpid()!):
>
> ...

For example:

```
void fatherProcess(int childpid)
{
  int status;
  pid_t pid;
  pid = wait(&status);

  if (pid == -1) {
    perror("wait");
    // handle this case 
  }
  if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("Child %ld exited successfully", pid_t);
  }
  // Handle the rest of the status cases accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `waitpid()` to get exit status of child process.

Example:

```
void fatherProcess(int childpid)
{
    int status;
    waitpid(childpid,&status,0);
    if(WIFEXITED(status)){
        print("exit status of child=%d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return;
}
```